# How to replace certain values in a dataset in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm creating a new column in my data set that is a copy of a preexisting column but I need to change 2 of the 7 values to something else.

I have tried doing this

```
Dataset$category_alt = Dataset$category_title
Dataset[Dataset$category_alt == "Shows"] <- "Other"
Dataset[Dataset$category_alt == "Nonprofits & Activism"] <- "Other"
```

But I receive this error
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, USvideos$category_alt == "Shows", value = "Other") :
duplicate subscripts for columns

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the new column name in the assignment.

```r
Dataset$category_alt = Dataset$category_title
Dataset$category_alt[Dataset$category_alt == "Shows"] <- "Other"
Dataset$category_alt[Dataset$category_alt == "Nonprofits & Activism"] <- "Other"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `%in%` to make the code clearer and shorter

```
Dataset$category_alt[Dataset$category_alt %in% c('Shows', 'Nonprofits & Activism')] <-'Other'
```

I usually prefer to use dplyr in such situations:

```
library(dplyr)

Dataset %>% mutate(category_alt = replace(category_alt, category_alt %in% c('Shows', 'Nonprofits & Activism'), 'Other))
```